# How to insert multiple check checked/unchecked boxes value into database from aspxgridview checkbox dataitemtemplate?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, devexpress

I'm trying to insert multiple checked/unchecked box value into database via submit button. after the submit button is clicked, the one or multiple checked check box value will be inserted into database first and followed by checked/unchecked images will appear on the clicked check boxes (which checked image represents value 1 and unchecked image represents value 0. )

Problem :

I have tried the method below but only able to insert one check box value into database, for the outcome the check box appeared as number instead of checked/unchecked image and required to refresh the page for the checked/unchecked images to appear.

Aspx

```
 <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="year" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ClientInstanceName="year" ValueType="System.Int32" Width="100px" CssClass="ddstyle mr10px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedIndexChanged"></dx:ASPxComboBox>
                                <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="month" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ClientInstanceName="month" ValueType="System.Int32" Width="100px" CssClass="ddstyle mr10px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedIndexChanged"></dx:ASPxComboBox>
                                <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="section" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ValueType="System.String" Width="100px" CssClass="ddstyle" OnSelectedIndexChanged="SelectedIndexChanged"></dx:ASPxComboBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <dx:ASPxGridView ID="LeaveSystem" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" KeyFieldName="EMP_NO;Year;Month" Width="100%">
                            <SettingsBehavior AllowDragDrop="false" AllowSort="false" />
                            <SettingsPager Mode="ShowAllRecords" />
                        </dx:ASPxGridView>
                        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="GeneralUpdateProgress" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
                            <ProgressTemplate>
                                <img id="gupLoading" src="../images/loadingscreen.gif" />
                            </ProgressTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdateProgress>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <dx:ASPxCallback ID="cb" ClientInstanceName="cb" runat="server" OnCallback="cb_Callback" ></dx:ASPxCallback>
                <dx:ASPxLabel ID="HiddenEmpID" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="HiddenEmpID" ClientVisible="false"></dx:ASPxLabel>     
                    <dx:ASPxButton ID="submitbtn" runat="server" Text="Submit"  Visible="true" OnClick="submitbtn_Click" AutoPostBack="false"></dx:ASPxButton>
```

VB.net

```
Sub CustomCheckBoxColumn(ByVal fieldName As String)
        Dim c As New GridViewDataColumn
        c.DataItemTemplate = New CheckBoxTemplate
        c.FieldName = fieldName
        Dim dayOfDate As New DateTime
        dayOfDate = getDate(fieldName)
        c.Caption = c.FieldName + vbNewLine + Replace(dayOfDate.ToString("dddd"), "??", "")
        c.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
        c.CellStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
        LeaveSystem.Columns.Add(c)
    End Sub

    Function getDate(ByVal fieldName As String) As DateTime
        Dim chosenDate As New DateTime
        chosenDate = Convert.ToDateTime(year.Value.ToString() + "-" + month.Value.ToString() + "-" + fieldName)
        Return chosenDate
    End Function

    Protected Sub SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        LeaveSystem.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Private Sub LeaveSystem_DataBinding(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LeaveSystem.DataBinding
        LeaveSystem.Columns.Clear()
        Dim sql As String = ""
        If section.Value.ToString() = "PT" Then
            sql = "select * from tb1"
        Else
            sql = "select * from tb2"
        End If
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt = GetMssql(sql)
        LeaveSystem.DataSource = dt

        Dim a As New GridViewDataColumn
        a.FieldName = "EMP_NO"
        a.Caption = "EMPID"
        LeaveSystem.Columns.Add(a)

        Dim b As New GridViewDataColumn
        b.FieldName = "CHI_NAME"
        b.Caption = "CNAME"
        LeaveSystem.Columns.Add(b)

        Dim fieldName As String = ""
        Dim lastDay As New Integer
        lastDay = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DirectCast(year.Value, Integer), DirectCast(month.Value, Integer))
        For i = 1 To lastDay
            If i.ToString().Length = 1 Then
                fieldName = "0" + i.ToString()
            Else
                fieldName = i.ToString


            End If
            CustomCheckBoxColumn(fieldName)
        Next

    End Sub


    Friend Class CheckBoxTemplate
        Implements ITemplate
        Public Sub InstantiateIn(ByVal container As Control) Implements ITemplate.InstantiateIn
            Dim checkbox As New ASPxCheckBox
            Dim gridContainer As GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer = CType(container, GridViewDataItemTemplateContainer)
            'Dim empid As String = gridContainer.Grid.GetRowValues(gridContainer.VisibleIndex, "EmpID").ToString()
            checkbox.AllowGrayed = False
            checkbox.CheckedImage.Url = "images/checked_image.png"
            checkbox.UncheckedImage.Url = "images/unchecked_image.png"
            checkbox.CssClass += "customcheckbox"
            checkbox.ID = "DateCheckBox"
            Dim list As New ArrayList

            list.Add(checkbox.Checked)

            Dim x As String

            For Each x In list
                checkbox.ClientSideEvents.CheckedChanged = String.Format("function (s, e) {{ cb.PerformCallback(HiddenEmpID.GetValue() + '|' + year.GetValue() + '|' + month.GetValue() + '|' + '{0}|' + s.GetChecked(""" & x & """)); }}", gridContainer.Column.FieldName)
                checkbox.Value = DataBinder.Eval(gridContainer.DataItem, gridContainer.Column.FieldName)

                If checkbox.Value = 1 Then
                    checkbox.Checked = True
                Else
                    checkbox.Checked = False
                End If
                checkbox.ValueType = GetType(Int32)
                checkbox.ValueUnchecked = 0
                checkbox.ValueChecked = 1


            Next

            container.Controls.Add(checkbox)

        End Sub

    End Class


    Protected Sub cb_Callback(source As Object, e As CallbackEventArgs)

        Session("par") = e.Parameter.Split("|"c)

    End Sub



    Protected Sub submitbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        If IsPostBack Then


            Dim p() As String = Session("par")
            p(1) = Session("year")
            p(2) = Session("month")

            'Dim p() As String = e.Parameter.Split("|"c)

            'p(0) = empid, p(1) = year, p(2) = month, p(3) = Date, p(4) = Boolean

            Dim list As New ArrayList

            list.Add(p(3))

            If p(4) = True Then
                p(4) = "1"
            Else
                p(4) = "0"
            End If

            Dim x As String

            For Each x In list

                Dim query As String = String.Format("UPDATE LeaveSystem SET [{3}] = '{4}', UpdateTime = GETDATE() WHERE EmpID = '{0}' and Year = '{1}' and Month = '{2}' IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 INSERT INTO LeaveSystem (EmpID, Year, Month, [{3}], UpdateTime) values ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{4}', GETDATE())", p(0), p(1), p(2), x, p(4))

                SetMssql(query)

            Next

        End If

    End Sub
```

Expected Result

```
                                              YEAR : 2019      MONTH: 4
      ------------------------------------------------------------------
      |EMP NO| 1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|.....|
      ------------------------------------------------------------------
      | 234  |v | | | | | | | | |  |  |  |  |  |v |  |  |  |  |  |.....|
      -------------------------------------------------------------------
   -->| 456  | v| | | | | | | | |  |  |v | v| v|  | v|  |  |  |  |.....|
      ------------------------------------------------------------------                                              
                                                       (Submit) (cancel)
```

Actual Result

```
                                              YEAR : 2019      MONTH: 4
      ------------------------------------------------------------------
      |EMP NO| 1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|.....|
      ------------------------------------------------------------------
      | 234  | 1| | | | | | | | |  |  |  |  |  | 1|  |  |  |  |  |.....|
      -------------------------------------------------------------------
   -->| 456  | 1| | | | | | | | |  |  |1 |  | 1|  0| 1|  |  |  |  |.....|
      ------------------------------------------------------------------                                              
                                                       (Submit) (cancel)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about VB.net. I am a PHP Developer.

but in this multiple radio check buttons value.

``````````````````````
<form method="POST" action="submit.php" >
<input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="male" />
<input type="checkbox" name="gender" value="female" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
$_POST['gender']={male,female};

`````````````````````
after submitting the form you will get an array of this multiple radio check value.
that's it.
``````````````````````

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing but this is not related to the topic.